# Why can't I find Dayspring Canyon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I look for Dayspring Canyon, it's not there. I've watched tons of videos showing where, but it's gone! And I'm past level ten and when I talk to guards, they don't say a thing, and Durak, or whatever his name is, NEVER confronts me! I desperate need help. I want to join because I HATE vampires, I'm a werewolf, and I want Bran.

Comment: The first question is: do you have the Dawnguard DLC installed?

Answer (score 2):

This location can sometimes be cut off if you haven't finished the prerequisite quests in either Dawnguard or the Companions questline. Most notably, if you have started the companions questline first, sometimes the entrance will be inaccessable until you finish the quest with Vilkas(?).

I would recommend finishing a couple more companions quests before continuing with the Dawnguard DLC

Answer (score 1):

You can find it next to "Broken Helm Hollow" it's to the bottom right of it. Try going to the area, there is a cave that will take you there. The place is "Stendarr's Beacon". If that doesn't work, try looking for an update.

Answer (score 0):

The entrance to day spring cavern doesnt look like a normal cave entrance. It is a very slim and odd looking entrance. I would suggest you go to Riften and wait for 24 hours and then just stand where you r for couple minutes and see if durak comes to you. You may have to do this a couple of times b4 he shows up.. also your have to be at least a level 10 for him to show up